# ssize_t and size_t give different values

Tags: c

I have a question about the following printout:

```
int logn = 32;
size_t count = (size_t)1<<logn; /* explicit cast required */
ssize_t count2 = (ssize_t)1<<logn;

fprintf(stderr, "count: %zu, count2: %zd\n", count, count2);
```

Output: 
count: 3119849472, count2: 4294967296

Why those two give different values?

Comment: It might help to print out the size of `size_t` and `ssize_t`

Comment: Note that `ssize_t` and `%zd` are not in the C standard; and also one major non-free compiler vendor was very late in actually supporting `%zu`

Comment: @Matt McNabb Note: `"%zd"` is in C11 (§7.21.6.1) and C99 (§7.19.6.1).

Answer (score 6):

```
ssize_t
```

is a signed type. In implementations where `ssize_t`  is 32-bit (or less), this expression:

```
 (ssize_t)1<< 32
```

invokes undefined behavior.

From the C Standard:

> (c99, 6.5.7p4) "If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 x 2<sup>E2</sup> is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: It's UB in both cases (`size_t` appears to have 32 bit on OP's platform), C99 6.5.7 p3 “If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.” 2**32 is 4294967296.

Comment: @mafso that's true, but `4294967296` is the expected result assuming `size_t` type can hold it.

Comment: I didn't mean to contradict you, your answer isn't wrong, it just sounds a little like it was UB only for signed types. I'm just wondering about that 3119849472 (which isn't a power of 2 at all) for the _unsigned_ version and about how that signed 32-bit variable passed to `fprintf` can hold 4294967296. Sure, we have UB, but what's really happening here?

Comment: What evidence do we have that OP has 32-bit `size_t` ?